# How to connect to Java ServerSocket from Remote Host

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Found some similar questions but no answer, so here goes -

Attached code is self contained, compilable and runnable to set up a server on my computer. Socket gets created, and I can do a `telnet <ip_address> 9162`  or `telnet localhost 9162` from my local machine. From a remote host, telnet does not get connected. Any ideas? TIA.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestServerSocket {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
                final int portNumber = 9162;
                System.out.println("Creating server socket on port " + portNumber);
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                while (true) {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        while (true) {
                                pw.print("What's you name? ");
                                pw.flush();
                                String str = br.readLine();
                                if (str.trim().length() == 0)
                                        break;
                                pw.println("Hello, " + str);
                        }
                        pw.close();
                        socket.close();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your system probably has a firewall enabled that prevents access from outside except to certain ports.  Or, if the remote is somewhere else on the Internet (not your local LAN) there is probably a router/firewall in the way also, and getting through that would require port forwarding.  You have to provide us with enough information about the locations (in IP address terms) of your system and the "remote" host.

Comment: ServerSockets listen at the local host. Your question is somewhat confused. Do you mean you can't *connect* to it from a remote host?

Comment: Yes, cannot connect from a remote host.The firewall is probably right, I cannot even ping this machine. The server is running on my laptop, and the remote host is another machine on my desk, both connected to the same network through LAN.

Comment: I found the answer - it *is* the firewall. Once I enable it to accept external connections, all is good. Thank you, Jim.

Comment: @ManidipSengupta what was the URL you gave to the remote client when your connection was successful? Was it something like "http://IP:port/appName" or was it just "http://IP:port" or something else?